# Laravel: InvalidArgumentException middleware error

Tags: php, html, laravel, routes, middleware

So I have a view called dashboard.blade.php and I only want users that are logged in to access this page. I have used a middleware to block access.

This is my route to dashboard:

```
 Route::get('/dashboard', 'PostController@getDashboard')->name('dashboard')->middleware('auth');
```

It does what it is supposed to do by letting logged in users to access the dashboard, but when a user that is not logged in tries to enter that page it gives the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentException
Route [login] not defined.
```

I understand that it is working because it is blocking the user. However, how would I go about redirecting the user back to the login page as an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application can't find any route named `login`. So you need to create a login named route. Something like:

```
Route::get('/login', 'AuthController@login')->name('login')
```